# GStreamer mpegtsmux produces empty output file

Tags: linux, transcoding

I'm trying to construct a GStreamer pipeline to transcode MPEG2 video and MPEG1 audio in a MPEGTS container to H.264 and AAC and output to a filesink.

The problem is: the output file is empty.
If I change the MPEGTS muxer to FLV muxer or Matroska, it works perfectly.

My pipeline:

```
/usr/bin/env GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="INPUTURL" is-live=true  ! decodebin name=demux demux. ! queue ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux demux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=2000 ! mux. mux. ! filesink location=/srv/hls/out.ts
```